# Modify Each String After Splitting Into Array

Tags: c#, split

I am capturing permutations of a contact number prefixes, and I would like to add a `SPACE` in each string after splitting them and store them in a separate array.

May I know other than using `foreach` on my `prefix` array, are there other ways to execute this?

```
string[] prefix = config.prefix.Split(','); //+65,65-,65,065

foreach (string p in prefix)
{
    add space to string
    store in another array
}
```

Comment: `config.prefix.Split(',').Select(x => <do stuff here>)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-syntax-examples-projection):

```
var result = config.prefix.Split(',')
   .Select(s => " " + s) // or some other handling
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use linq to operate on the content of the array.

Just do

```
var prefix = config.prefix.Split(','); //+65,65-,65,065

var newArray = prefix
    .Select(str => DoStuffWithString(str))
    .ToArray();
```

the `newArray` variable will the contain a new array with the manipualted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.ConvertAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netcore-3.1),

```
var result = Array.ConvertAll(config.prefix.Split(','), x => " "+ x);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NIVzmQ)